# Error C1001 "Internal Compiler Error"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, porting, visual-c++-6, c1001

I am trying to run a VC++ 6 project in VS2010. In that am getting:

> Internal Compiler error.. error C1001

Can anyone please tell me how to rectify that error? I Googled for this and I found reinstalling the Service Pack will solve this issue. But it didn't.

Comment: Not really sure how we're supposed to help you fix this: you forgot to post the code!

Comment: I was also getting this error and sent a message to MS. Today they responded that they have fixed it: See if this link explains the same problem you are having: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/926865/wdmh-internal-compiler-error-with-code-analysis.html?childToView=975443#comment-975443

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft Developer Network suggests that you remove some optimizations in your code: [Fatal Error C1001](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y19zxzb2.aspx). Once you've worked out which optimization is causing the issue, you can use a #pragma to disable that optimization in just that area:

```
// Disable the optimization
#pragma optimize( "", off )
...
// Re-enable any previous optimization
#pragma optimize( "", on )
```

Hope that helps to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

In order for me to resolve this issue while targeting DotNet 3.5 I had to apply the visual studio 2008 sp1 as well as a seemingly unrelated hotfix http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976656
that cleared it up.
Keep in mind that the IDE is Visual studio but the msbuild is from your installed Visual studio 2008